# Prove almost sure convergence series of independent variables

Tags: measure-theory

Given $X_i$ i.i.d random variables, $|X_i| \leq l$ for some $l>0$, $p_k = P(X_i = k) > 0 \ \forall k$.

Let $N_n(k) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}1_{X_i = k}$ and let $\prod_n = \prod_{k=1}^l (p_k)^{(N_n(k))}$.

Prove the sequence $\frac{1}{n}\log \prod_n $ converges almost surely and compute the limit.

I try this using the 3 Series theorem but I am unsure how to define the sequence to prove a.s. convergence using the 3 series theorem.  Breaking down the sequence I arrive at the following:

$$A_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{l}\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{X_i = k}\log(p(X_1 = k)) $$

I'm not sure how to create the sequence though to prove the 3 criteria of the 3 series theorem if that is what is required for the proof.

Comment: By $|X_i| < l$ for some $l$ You mean that $X_i$ are bounded by $l$ ? If yes, what is the probability that $P(X_i = l+1)$?

Comment: It would be 0, the $X_i$s are basically discrete I think based on the definition

Comment: $N_n(k))$ is the # of times the Xis = k so the bound would be n given the indicator function, how are you getting $l(l+1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the proof I assumed that $X_i > 0.$

Firstly, by boundness of $X_i$ there exists $m \leq l$ such that
$$ P(X_i = m) > 0,~~P(X_i = m+1) =0.$$
Let's denote
$$ \prod_n = p_1^{N_n(1)}\dots p_m^{N_n(m)}, $$
now by property of $\log$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n} \log ( \prod_n ) &=  \log ( p_1^{N_n(1)/n}\dots p_m^{N_n(m)/n} ) \\&= \sum_{i=1}^m \log( p_i^{N_n(i)/n} ).
\end{align}
For each $i \in \{1,2,\dots,m\}$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \log( p_i^{N_n(i)/n } ) \\&= \log( p_i^{  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} N_n(i)/n} ). 
\end{align}
By strong law of large numbers
\begin{align}
& \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} N_n(i)/n \\ &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n 1_{\{X_k = p_i \}} }{ n } = p_i, ~~~~\text{a.s}.
\end{align}
Hence
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \log ( \prod_n ) = \log ( p_1^{p_1}\dots p_m^{p_m} ).$$

Comment: I agree we need SLLN argument here for the $N_n(k)$ but can't we simply set each $X_i = 1_{X_i=k}$ and thus $E|X_i| \le \inf$ and where each $X_i$ is i.i.d as stated and so by SLLN $N_n(k) / n $ = $S_n/n$ = $E(S_n)/n$ = $np_k/n$ = $p_k$ and then we're done since the log sum is a finite sum of bounded terms?

Comment: Your idead is also fine. We can firstly show that $N_n(k)/n \rightarrow p_k$ so then $p_k^{N_n(k)/n} \rightarrow p_k^{p_k}$. And since we have finite number of $p_k$'s by laws of limit we can conclude that our limit is equal to the product of $p_k^{p_k}$'s

Comment: My only lasting question here is on the notion of identical distribution, if two r.v.s are i.i.d say X1, X2 then f(X1) and f(X2) are independent but are they also ident distributed, f:borel -> borel? I think that's correct but I haven't yet proved it but wanted to confirm

Comment: You do You mean by f:borel -> borel?. So in general if $X_1, X_2$ are independent borel measurable random variables then for any borel measurable funcion $f$, $f(X_1), f(X_2)$ are also independent random variables .

Comment: correct but are they identical in distribution too, f(X1) and f(X2) iff X1 and X2 are i.i.d?

Comment: Yes they are. We have $P(f(X_i) \in A) = P(X_i \in f^{-1}(A))$ , here $f^{-1}$ is invers image of $f$. So if $X_1, X_2$ are i.i.d then $f(X_1), f(X_2)$ also